# Spring Integration - How to debug 'Dispatcher has no Subscribers'?

Tags: java, spring, debugging, spring-integration

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.0.RELEASE, Spring Integration 4.3.1.RELEASE, Spring Integration DSL 1.2.0.M1.

What I'm trying to do:

I'm writing an application that will read files from FTP and local file system (using inbound channel adapters), transfer the files to a local working directory (using file outbound gateways), process, then move them to a final destination (file outbound gateway/adapters).

I'm running into an issue with 'Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel' errors. I believe this probably means something in the context is broken and the Integration components are not starting. The Context itself says it is active when I debug.

My actual configuration is fairly large, so I'm not looking for someone to find the solution for me. I'm looking for some guidance on where to look and how to figure out what component is complaining.

The actual error is below.

```
DEBUG [integration.channel.ExecutorChannel] [task-scheduler-1] preSend on channel 'errorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application:test.fileReadingFlow.channel#1'.
```

The `fileReadingFlow` is an `InboundChannelAdapter` which reads files from a directory (basically, what I asked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041341/spring-integration-dsl-outbound-gateway-with-access-to-headers). There is nothing complex in it. The adapter sends the message to a `.log()` handler, enriches headers, sends it to a handler (`Files.outboundgateway`), and finally a `MessageChannel`.

What I've tried:

- I've walked through the chain of `MessageChannel`s and things line up (no misspellings, all `Bean` exist).
- I've added more `LoggingHandler`s in the `fileReadingFlow` to identify where the message errors.
- I've removed portions of the `fileReadingFlow` to see if I could get the message farther along.
- I've removed some `Component`s to see if I could find the problem.
- I added debug logging for `org.springframework.integration` and nothing resembling an error or warning appears.

What I found was that the first time the flow tried to do something other than logging (even enrichHeaders), the Dispatcher error occurred, and the message ended up in the `errorChannel`. When I changed the `fileReadingFlow` to only read the file, log a message, and terminate with an empty Handler, I got the Dispatcher error. Thus, I'm fairly certain the issue is not with the `fileReadingFlow` itself.

Other than removing each `Component` one by one, is there a way to track down what is causing the error?

EDIT:

Source:

```
@Bean(name = "fileReadingFlow")
@Scope("prototype")
@Profile("test")
public IntegrationFlow testFileReadingFlow(MyEntity entity) {

    return IntegrationFlows.from(s -> s.file(new File("someFolder")))
            .filter(fileListFilterBuilder.buildFileListFilter(File.class))
            , endpointConfigurer -> endpointConfigurer.poller(poller)
    )
            .log(DEBUG, "com.myco.testFileReadingFlow")
            .enrichHeaders(h ->
                    h.header("entity", entity)
                            .header(FOLDER_NAME, entity.getFolder())
            )
            .log(DEBUG, "com.myco.testFileReadingFlow", message -> "after headers")
            .handle(Files.outboundGateway("workingFolder").deleteSourceFiles(true).autoCreateDirectory(true))
                .log(DEBUG, "com.myco.testFileReadingFLow", message -> "sending message to aggregatingFileChannel " + message)
                .channel("aggregatingFileChannel")
                .get();
    }
@Bean
public MessageChannel aggregatingFileChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()).get();

}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow aggregatingFlow() {

    // Read from the aggregatingFileChannel
    return from("aggregatingFileChannel")
            <...>
            .get();
}
```

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EntityScan(
        basePackages = { "com.myco.model" }
)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.myco.rest"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).web(false).run(args);

        MyEntitySvc entitySvc = context.getBean(MyEntitySvc.class);

        List<MyEntity> entities = entitySvc.findAllActive();

        AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = context.getBeanFactory();

        entities.forEach(entity -> {
            IntegrationFlow flow = (IntegrationFlow) context.getBean("fileReadingFlow", entity);

            beanFactory.getBean(entity.getFolder() + MyConstants.ADAPTER, Lifecycle.class).start();
    }
```

Solution:

Per my comments below, the `@Prototype` method did work at some point, but I broke it and could not easily rollback the change. Using Gary and Artem's suggestions, I tried changed to using the `IntegrationFlowContext` method. In order to retain the runtime startup, profile driven injection, etc. I had originally, I moved the definition of my `IntegrationFlow` from a `@Configuration` class to a `@Service` class. That way I can inject the `IntegrationFlowContext` into the `Service`, and implement different versions of the `Service` for my different profiles without requiring my `Application` to know about the `Profile`. The main method goes from extracting a `Bean` from `Context` and manually starting it to retrieving a `Service` and calling a method.

```
@Service
@Profile("test")
public class TestFlowSvc implements FlowSvc {
    public IntegrationFlow testFileReadingFlow(Vendor vendor) {
        return // As previous Flow
    }

    public void startFileReadingFlow(MyEntity entity) {

        IntegrationFlow flow = testFileReadingFlow(entity);

        integrationFlowContext.register(flow, true);
    }
}
```

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EntityScan(
        basePackages = { "com.myco.model" }
)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.myco.rest"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).web(false).run(args);

        MyEntitySvc entitySvc = context.getBean(MyEntitySvc.class);
        FlowSvc flowSvc = context.getBean(FlowSvc.class);
        List<MyEntity> entities = entitySvc.findAllActive();

        entities.forEach(entity -> {
            flowSvc.startFileReadingFlow(entity);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have `Dispatcher has no Subscribers` error when there is some `SubscribableChannel` without active `Subscriber` (`MessageHandler` in term of Spring Integration). 
"Active" means there is no one defined at all or it is in a stopped state.

So, for your problem with the `application:test.fileReadingFlow.channel#1` `MessageChannel`, I'd look into that `fileReadingFlow` `IntegrationFlow` one more time and find what is on the second anonymous `DirectChannel`.

I can't figure out the easy way to debug such a problem because there is a `MessageChannel`, but there is nothing to track, because of `Dispatcher has no Subscribers`.

So, please, show that `fileReadingFlow` `IntegrationFlow` definition and let's fix the problem together!

Looking to your related question it should be this one:

```
.handle(Files.outboundGateway())
```

which may be just in stopped state.

But we can't be sure until the actual code.

Comment: Enable DEBUG logging and look for messages like this...

    `14:20:51.967 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting beans in phase 0`
    `14:20:51.968 [main] INFO  o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel - Channel 'application.fromKafka.channel#0' has 1 subscriber(s).`

Comment: @Artem I added the example flow. @Gary, I saw messages like that. my `fileReadingFlow` does not have any. I assumed that was because it was a prototype scope, and started manually (included in edit).

Comment: Since you have no references to the prototype scope bean no instances are created. In any case, you can't use prototype scope for `IntegrationFlow` beans - they generate many beans internally which will not be in that scope.

Comment: I think your problem that you have `@Scope("prototype")`. And your second subscriber is really not started. Since you use Java DSL 1.2 you can cast `IntegrationFlow` to `Lifecycle` and start all the dependant beans. To start just one `FileReadingMessageSource` isn't enough in case of `@Scope("prototype")`

Comment: What Gary says is true anyway. Even if your `IntegrationFlow` is `prototype`, all other dependants are not. Consider the new `IntegrationFlowContext` technique: https://spring.io/blog/2016/07/08/java-dsl-for-spring-integration-1-2-m1-and-1-1-3-are-available

Comment: Interesting. I'll try to use the `IntegrationFlowContext` and report back. One note, this was working (as in, I read messages using the technique above and had them flow through several channels and flows successfully). I did a large refactor and added some functionality (an additional OutboundChannel several layers removed from this code) before this issue occurred. So, prototype had to work at one point. I'm not sure what exactly caused it to stop working.

Comment: @Gary @Artem Thanks for your assistance. `IntegrationFlowContext` seems to be working. I updated my question with the solution based on this, and accepted the above answer.

Comment: LGTM! Contgats! And that is one more +1 to our intention to let to register flows at runtime